# XSLT : copy adds extra spaces around CDATA

Tags: xml, xslt, space

I am trying to process an xml file specific for an application. When I try to copy source xml as it is in output I figured out that processor adds spaces and new lines around CDATA.

Do you know any way to avoid this ? I want to edit some values but need to clarify this issue.

Here is the source xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Application>
  <name><![CDATA[Flow1]]></name>
  <versionInfo><![CDATA[572573
572573
619888]]></versionInfo>
  <configUser><![CDATA[USER1]]></configUser>
  <protected>0</protected>
  <productRevision>
    <productNumber><![CDATA[CER]]></productNumber>
    <revision><![CDATA[DER]]></revision>
  </productRevision>
</Application>
```

Here is the xsl file I use:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:strip-space elements="/Application/name" />
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
            </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And here is the output:

```
<Application>
   <name>      <![CDATA[Flow1]]>

   </name>
   <versionInfo>      <![CDATA[572573
572573
619888]]>

   </versionInfo>
   <configUser>      <![CDATA[USER1]]>

   </configUser>
   <protected>0</protected>
   <productRevision>
      <productNumber>         <![CDATA[CER]]>

      </productNumber>
      <revision>         <![CDATA[DER]]>

      </revision>
   </productRevision>
</Application>
```

Thanks

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. Which processor are you using?

Comment: This looks very buggy behaviour. The output shouldn't even contain any CDATA sections.

Comment: You both are right I was testing wiht xsl.exe coming with oracle client and seems it is not the right processor. I used xsltproc in cygwin and behaviour is now same as you mentioned. My bad...

Comment: I'm facing the same issue. Will this issue happen because of old xslt version?